# Open an Flutter Activity from a native-built AAR

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I'm building a lib for Android native with a Flutter codebase.

- Have a Flutter project, export it to an AAR files
- Have an Android module, which has the AAR from Flutter, open the Flutter Activity

```dart
class IntegratedActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    val CHANNEL = "SOME_CHANNEL"
    lateinit var memberCode: String
    lateinit var token: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        print(intent.getStringExtra("memberCode").toString())
        memberCode = intent.getStringExtra("memberCode").toString()
        token = intent.getStringExtra("token").toString()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

        MethodChannel(
            flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,
            CHANNEL
        ).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "getToken") {
                result.success(token)
            } else if (call.method == "getMemberCode") {
                result.success(memberCode)
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- I can open the Activity normally from an object

```dart
class MainSDK() {

    companion object {

        lateinit var context: Context
        lateinit var token: String
        lateinit var memberCode: String

        fun init(context: Context, memberCode: String, token: String) {
            this.context = context
            this.memberCode = memberCode
            this.token = token
        }

        fun start() {
            val intent = Intent(context, IntegratedActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("memberCode", memberCode)
            intent.putExtra("token", token)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

But when I build this Android project to AAR files, import it to another project, I got instant crash when call the Activity

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 8650
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/flutter/embedding/android/FlutterActivity;
at com.example.giftsdkdemo.LinkIDSDK.<clinit>(Unknown Source:0)
at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda$0(MainActivity.kt:36)
at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$s7ZgWS1zeqgcdOUfUDpDB0yzUWo(Unknown Source:0)
...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.myapplication/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~MTsHjZPw32gf4DUs4jtPlQ==/com.example.myapplication-OQjMcBeWVJq4M45jhKvZCw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~MTsHjZPw32gf4DUs4jtPlQ==/com.example.myapplication-OQjMcBeWVJq4M45jhKvZCw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at com.example.mainsdkdemo.MainSDK.<clinit>(Unknown Source:0) 
at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda$0(MainActivity.kt:36) 
at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$s7ZgWS1zeqgcdOUfUDpDB0yzUWo(Unknown Source:0) 
at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2) 
...
```

The AAR doesn't seems to have any Flutter-related things.
[image]

Is the AAR did not contains the Flutter SDK or something ? How can I build for it to be run normally ?

Comment: Not sure if you are following: https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app/android/project-setup

Comment: yes, I've been following the method A. But it stops at the adding libs to the Android project. We go further with exporting that project into an AAR.

Comment: were you able to accomplish this? We are also building fat aar with flutter included, but we have only GeneratedPluginRegistrant in it and no libflutter.so files so far.

Comment: no. Still don't have the solution